# Subscriptions are cancelled without user's action

Tags: android, in-app-subscription

I have IAP in my Android app and it all used to work well.
I rewrote my app completely using Flutter and am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase for this.

I don't think the switch to Flutter can be of any problem for this. The package just triggers the native purchasing and all goes ok, the user gets charged and has the feature he wanted.

But I noticed that lately subscriptions are being cancelled. I had 3 subscriptions since nov 7, and all three have been cancelled after (ignoring seconds) **exactly 3 days and 10 minutes**!

[image]

What is going on here, what is cancelling (all of the?) subscriptions after 3 days 10 minutes?

I found out about this because a user of my app contacted me because his subscription was cancelled and doesn't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I had a chat with support and I was pointed out to this page: http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fgoogle%2Fplay%2Fbilling%2Fbilling_library_releases_notes%232_0_acknowledge

So it seems you have to acknowledge purchases now.